# Buffer Overflow PoC code \x11(setup sound

Tags: metasploit, buffer-overflow

I am reading the PWK course book, the chapter of **Linux Buffer Overflow**:

> Once the crossfire application is running, we can use the following Proof of Concept
>   (PoC) code, found on the Exploit Database to crash the application.

```
...
crash="\x41" * 4379
buffer = "\x11(setup sound " + crash + "\x90\x00#"
...
s.send(buffer)
```

> Once we run this script, the debugger spits out the following error message, which clearly indicates a buffer overflow condition in the **setup sound** command:

Then a window popup shows "... segmentation fault. The address 0x41414141 cannot be accessed". This is the expected result, because EIP has been overwritten by \x41\x41\x41\x41.

**My question:**

I understand those buffer overflow, EIP stuff. My question is just about this special string before *\x41\x41...\x41*:

```
"\x11(setup sound
```

What is this means? What means setup sound command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://vuldb.com/?id.29211 there is a memory corruption in the function `setup` of `request.c`. While I'm not familiar with the full details of the vulnerability, the exploit connects to a socket so it is presumably part of the networking protocol. The `\x11setup sound` string is likely the syntax that causes the server to invoke the `setup` function in request.c if you cannot cause the code execution to enter the vulnerable function then you cannot trigger the vulnerability.

You usually see a semblance of correct syntax in network protocol and file based exploits for this reason. This exploit for example, contains several FTP syntax commands to reach the vulnerable function: https://github.com/wireghoul/sploit-dev/blob/master/freeFTPD-bof.pl

Comment: i understand your 1st paragraph already. In the link of your 2nd paragraph, the vulnerable function is "egghunter"?

Comment: No, an egg Hunter is an exploitation technique for overcoming small shell code byte space. I never did root cause analysis on the freeftpd vulnerability, I just popped shell and moved on. If I had to guess it would be in a function related to "receive password" or "authenticate" as the overflow string is the supplied password for a username. I included it as an example of why you may often see text that isn't part of the "exploit code" in exploits, such as initiating a login session and supplying a username to make the server enter a state where the vulnerable function is called.